# MVC3: Client Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mini form that consists of all select boxes and checkbox lists.

I have the data annotations in the viewmodel already set up. So if i submit the form (without javascript enabled), `ModelState.IsValid` works like it's supposed to.

But in the client validation, I'm having issues. I have unobtrusive jquery validation on, but the when i do `$("#form").valid()`, it always returns true.

I'm not sure how to customize this and check for conditions. E.g., i have a checkboxlist which by default has nothing checked. So if nothing is checked, `.valid()` should return false. Also, 2 of the dropdowns have a 'please select' option as their first, but jquery still returns valid. Server side `ModelState.IsValid` works for both of these.

The following is an example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "miniForm" })) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NinjaType)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NinjaType, Model.NinjaTypeList) // First value is '0'. Rest of the list is of type STRING
</div>

/// following is the rendered html code as i created a helper for it which i've omitted in this example
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="poo1" name="pie" value="one" />one</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="poo2" name="pie" value="two" />two</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" id="poo3" name="pie" value="three" />three</li>
</ul>

<input type="submit" id="submitButton" />
}
```

If it helps, this is the POST Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index(SuperDooperNinjaViewModel m)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return Redirect("win");
    else 
        return Redirect("fail");
}
```

I was thinking that i'd do it the old fashioned way on `$('#submitButton').click();`, but I have a feeling there might be a better way to do this. Another way I've thought of, is turn it into an Ajax form. So in the server side response, instead of `Redirect("fail");`, i return a `JsonResult`.

**So in summary, what would the best route be here to validating this form?**

- NinjaType's value must **not** be '0'
- At least **one** check box must be checked.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

ViewModel:

```
public class SuperDooperViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string NinjaType {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<SelectItemList> { get;set; }

    [Required]
    public string[] pie {get;set;} // checkbox
    public IEnumerable<string> PieList { get;set; } // list of values for checkbox
}
```

In jquery, i'm testing it like this:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#miniForm").valid())
         alert("valid");
    else
         alert("fail");
});
```

Comment: @CjCoax, what does this script has to do with validation?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, apologies I meant "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but for now, i've thrown the checkboxlist extension out, and just manually done this:

```
@foreach(var nt in Model.NinjaTypeList)
{
    <li>@Html.CheckBox("pie", new { @id = nt })</li>
}
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NinjaType)
```

In jquery, i've attached an event to the checkboxes:

```
$('input[name=pie]').click(function(){
    var pie = "";
    $('input[name=pie]').each(function(i) {
       if ($(this).is(':checked'))
           pie += $(this).val() + ';';
    });
    $("#NinjaType").val(pie);
});
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(SuperDooperViewModel m, string[] pie)
{
    /// I've add the following as a work around:
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.NinjaType) // no reason it should be, but it's a sort of failsafe
    {
         if(pie.Any())
              m.NinjaType = string.Join(";", pie.Where(w => w != "false"));
    }

    // rest of the controller here
}
```

This basically does what I want, but it seems like a bit of a work around to me. Any improvements would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For the dropdownlist it's simple:

```
public class SuperDooperNinjaViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string NinjaType { get; set; }

    public SelectList NinjaTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.NinjaType, 
    Model.NinjaTypeList,
    "Please Select"
)
```

Now for the checkboxes you talked about some HTML helper that is generating them but I can't see this helper emitting any HTML5 `data-*` attributes which are used for unobttrusive validation.

Comment: The thing about ninjatype is, it's actually a string, but I set the value of the first option as '0'.
As for the checkboxes, i haven't added the data-* stuff on there, but how would i validate it for just ONE ticked, if all of them have a 'data-required' attribute?

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear, I have updated my answer so that NinjaType is a string and it still works for the dropdown. As far as the checkboxes are concerned, well, in order to validate this condition you could write a custom validation attribute.

Comment: I have pretty much that identical code to what you have in your answer already. Only difference is, I'm using IEnumerable<SelectListItem> instead of SelectList for the NinjaTypeList. So it works in server side, just clientside it doesn't do anything/returns as valid.

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear, `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` should also work. Where are you calling this `$("#form").valid()` method?

Comment: just updated my answer with the jquery i'm using to test. This is the first time i'm doing mvc, and therefore never done validation before on this, so i'm not sure if i'm on the right track or not.

Comment: Is the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script referenced? Also you'd better do this check in the `.submit` event of the form instead of the `.click` event on some button.

Comment: Yes i just added it (i just had jquery.validate.min.js before). still didn't make a difference. I've also changed the jquery function to handle $(form).submit()

Comment: That's weird. If you have done all that, the code should at least for the dropdown list. By default its first element is `Please Select` which has no value, and because the NinjaType property is decorated with the Required attribute, if the user doesn't select any value, the validation will fail.

Comment: Ok your last comment made sense. I noticed my list had no real set value, only text in the <option>text</option> tag, it caused it to fail. I made the list set the value of it, and the jquery function has returned false if the first option is selected. THanks for this.
BUT, the checkbox dilemma still remains. Any ideas for this?

Comment: @rudeovski ze bear, yes I have an idea, it involves writing a customvalidation attribute. Will post an example.

Comment: I've tried adding the data-* stuff to the checkboxes now, and it didn't make a difference. Because of the multiple checkboxes with the same name, it sends it to the controller as a string[]. Do you think it might be better if i assign a hidden field with the selected values and validate on that instead?